# The uniqueness of direct sums in the algebraic category

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $B$ and $C$ be $A$-algebra, and let
$i: B \to B \otimes_A C, j: C \to B \otimes_A C$
be standard immersion.
I want to prove that
for any $A$-algebra $D$ and any $A$-homomorphism
$f: B \to D, g: C \to D$,
there is only one $A$-homomorphism
$h: B \otimes_A C \to D$ that satisfies
$f = h \circ i, g = h \circ j$.

I can see that $h$ is obtained from
$B \times C \to D , (b, c) \to f (b) g (c)$
because this is $A$-bilinear.

Please tell me how to prove the uniqueness of $h$.

Comment: A standard trick for proving uniqueness of morphisms is to assume the existence of a second such map $k:B \otimes_A C \to D$ and then derive that for all pure tensors $b \otimes c$, $k(b \otimes c) = h(b \otimes c)$.

Comment: Thak you. I didn't realize it was so easy!!